# BulletedList showing the listitem as horizontal, instead of vertical in the content page

Tags: asp.net

BulletedList showing as horizontal ListItem instead of vertical ListItems in content page of Asp.Net. Does this have to do with anything with the masterpage design?

Comment: Take a look at it's `RepeatDirection` property.

Comment: actually its mistyped , its BulletedList instead of ButtonList

Comment: Then edit your question please. And while you are add it, post your markup / code, relevant css. Everything we need to reproduce your problem.